# Why is the box shadow only visible after scrolling?

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll, box-shadow

I've been trying for ages to figure out why the box shadow on my top menu is not visible when you first navigate to each page, but appears once you start scrolling.

This is the site: http://gourmetsailing.co.nz/DRAFT/charters.html

The class with the shadow is .navbar-wrapper

```
.navbar-wrapper {
background-color: #FFFFFF;
width: 100%;
margin: auto;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); /* [h-offset] [v-offset] [blur radius] [color: red, green, blue, opacity]; */
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);}
```

It's worth mentioning that I am also using stickUp to get the menu to stick to the top of the page: http://lirancohen.github.io/stickUp/

Perhaps some kind of conflict with that script?

Comment: could u share the jquery?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try adding `position: relative` to your `navbar-wrapper` class.

***Here's what's happening:***

When you start to scroll, the `position: relative` declaration is dynamically added to the `div` with class `navbar-wrapper` as an inline style, firing the box shadow.

If you add this declaration to the class directly, the box shadow is there from the start.

Comment: I just tested this in the browser, Michael's solution seems to solve the problem, let us know if it works @Andrea it is an interesting issue.

Comment: Yes this solution worked perfectly thanks @Michael_B